# How to make Lookup Field and Date field work on Visualforce page in Salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

I tried using a basic VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <apex:form >
        <div>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.ParentId}"/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Period End Date" for="date" style="font-weight:900"/><apex:input value="{!endDate}" type="auto" id="date"/>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But in SF1 for Android the pop window does not load but does on    iphone    ipad      one/one.app
I found something mentioning lookups are not supported but can't find how to make these work for android. (Am I just not supposed to have the functionality at all???)

The apex:input in the documentation states it will load the devices native widget.. Again this works on    iphone    ipad      one/one.app    and completely crashes on android.

Any hints, tips or tricks I need to use? It seems all my issues are around the Android device and can't figure out why..

*note: I am using an android device with version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Its always a pain to develop for android!! 
I'd suggest using jqueryUI for date picker. For salesforce1, never use apex tags as it does not support all devices and it will not be rendered as expected. 
for look up I'd suggest using custom pick list using pure HTML-5 tags. 
Using forms is not advisable, instead use remoting functions in javascript, like VF remoting or forceTK libraries. You will have a better control of your application.

Comment: Seems like I shouldn't have to make that much effort. The documentation says that this should be working and supported. The fact that it is not seems like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do things so complicated.
Use regular HTML5 : apex:inpu type="date" (or number... you can also use other html5 parameters if you add html-, like htlm-step

Comment: I am using apex:input currently. I had the type as date previously and it did not load so I tried changing to auto and still will not load.

Answer (score 0):

For date field, we can use jquery datepicker class or simply HTML5 . For lookup, we need to implement custom picklist functionality or we can display all possible lookup record as a picklist value.